# tbl_summary() and add_p() -- Pull the name of the test (as it would appear in footnote) Into a Column

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to be able to pull a reader-friendly name of the type of test used for p-value calculation into its own column. Theoretically, I would think it should be possible to use the same object that the footnotes use (but how has been difficult).

Sample data:

```
library(gtsummary)
df <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10), sample(c("orange","pink","green"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 10, replace = TRUE))

names(df) <- c("a","b","c","outcome")
preds <- c("a","b","c")

gt <- df %>% select(all_of(preds), outcome) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = outcome, percent = 'row') %>%
add_p()
```

If I do

```
gt %>% modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**", 
  test_name ~ "**Test Used**")
```

I get the statistic value (great!) and the test used, but the test used is formatted in function name.

I want it to be more reader-friendly. e.g. instead of "fisher.test" I'd like it to print "Fisher's exact test" the same way that the footnotes do. Can this be done?

Comment: You can get the same names used in the foot note with `sapply(gt$meta_data$test_result, function(x) x$df_result[["method"]])`. Does that help?

Comment: @MrFlick Unfortunately there's not  (as far as I know) a way to pull a set of generated values like this into a new column when using gtsummary.

Answer (score 0):

The code below illustrates how you can access the test names from the internals of a gtsummary table. That said, there is no guarantee that internals do not change at some point in the future, and these would not be considered breaking changes as they are not features surfaced by the gtsummary package.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

tbl <- 
  trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    include = age, 
    missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  add_p()

# access the names from the gtsummary internals
tbl$meta_data$test_result[[1]]$df_result
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   statistic p.value method                 alternative
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>      
#> 1      4323   0.718 Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks... After reviewing your advanced documentation it seems this can be used in `modify_table_body()`. I'd like to personally advocate for making it a more accessible option.

Comment: i do have plans for this, but no timeline i can provide unfortunately

Comment: Thanks Professor Sjoberg. If anyone is curious in the meantime I used `modify_table_body(~.x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(test_used = list(test_result[[row_number()+3]]$method)) %>% dplyr::relocate(add_stat_1, .before = statistic) %>% modify_header(test_used~ "**Test Used**))`  after many other approaches failed to consistently pull the right name by row.